# Как выполнить конкатенацию vector`ов c++, нигде не могу найти доступного ответа в интернете

Tags: c++, vector

Был бы рад помощи с написанием алгоритма быстрой сортировки на [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).
Недавно начал углублено изучать C++ после Python. И не могу найти нигде в интернете, как объединить три вектора в один.
Грубо говоря, как перевести `[1, 2, 3]` + `[4, 5, 6]` на питоне в C++.
Заранее спасибо.
Мой код отказывается запускаться, не понимаю почему так происходит.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector <int> quick_sort(vector <int> arr) {

    if (arr.size() <= 1) {
        return arr;
    }

    int chosen = arr[arr.size() / 2];
    vector <int> less, equal, greater;
    for (int el : arr) {
        if (el < chosen) {
            less.push_back(el);
        }
        else if (el > chosen) {
            greater.push_back(el);
        }
        else {
            equal.push_back(el);
        }
    }

    arr.clear();

    return merge(quick_sort(less), equal, quick_sort(greater));
}

vector <int> merge(vector<int> v1, vector<int> v2, vector <int> v3) {
    vector <int> result;

    for (int el : v1) result.push_back(el);
    v1.clear();
    for (int el : v2) result.push_back(el);
    v2.clear();
    for (int el : v3) result.push_back(el);
    v3.clear();
    return result;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    vector <int> s = { 5, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    for (int el : s)
        cout << el << ' ';
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `result.insert(result.end(),v1.begin(),v1.end());` === `result push_back v1`

Comment: Вы немного не поняли (последствия использования Питона?) суть [быстрой сортировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). Разделение массива на 2 части производится **по месту** (т.е. никакая дополнительная память не используется). Поэтому никакая конкатенация не нужна.  Кстати, обращаю внимание на то, что  в псевдокодах по ссылке (в вике) есть существенное упущение. В рекурсии нужно в первую очередь сортировать более короткий подмассив (это обеспечит глубину рекурсии не более чем log N)